# WebClient and CredentialCache (.net)

Tags: .net, proxy, webclient

I have the following code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

and I have a proxy configured in Internet Options. The proxy requires authentication. If I fill in my credentials in Internet Explorer, it works.

However, it doesn't work with webClient. I'm debugging with Wireshark to make sure I understand it at all. If I do

```
 webClient.Proxy = new NetworkCredential("<myusername>", "<mypassword>");
```

Then I see in Wireshark a CONNECT request with the credentials, and the proxy works.

However, I've also tried

```
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

and

```
webClient.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

and

```
webClient.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

And in none of those cases do I see a CONNECT request with any credentials whatsoever. Even though I have filled in the credentials in IE, in Chrome and in the included browser in the app. And they do show up under "Manage your credentials" in "User Accounts".

I can't check whether the CredentialCache has values because it's always empty.

Target framework is .NET 3.5, using Visual C# 2010. I haven't tried to set it in the app.config yet, as I don't know yet whether that's practical for what I'm building.

Am I doing it wrong? Misunderstanding something? Is there a way to check whether CredentialCache has any values set?